# "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout" error when adding an Android WebView to a LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, debugging, webview, android-linearlayout

I get this error when using the following code, what is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">  

</LinearLayout>  

linearLayout1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);  
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);  
webView=new WebView(this.getApplicationContext()); // also with just (this) 
webView.setLayoutParams(params);  
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
       @Override  
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {  
           Log.d("finished",url);  

       }  
     }  
    );  
linearLayout1.addView(webView);  
//also tried linearLayout1.forceLayout(); linearLayout1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: Try ..LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT..

Comment: @appserv thanks, it seems to work now, some messages still are issued but the application doesn't block and so it works well. It is very strange because I read that FILL_PARENT is just tolerated for backward compatibility...

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated. You should use MATCH_PARENT instead.

Comment: @P5music - any idea why switching back works? I ran into this same issue, and switching back to FILL_PARENT from MATCH_PARENT worked on older Android versions (2.3.7). Both work on 4.0+. I realize that it's depreciated, but it works, and it's unclear what a workaround would be given the strangeness of the "fix" (According to the docs, it was simply renamed).